# Need to compute correct output

Tags: c#

I am coding in C#

This code is in the Main()

```
double rate = 0.10;
double surge = 0.25;
int phoneBill = 75;
double totalAmount = phoneBill + rate + surge;

WriteLine("New Phone Bill");
WriteLine("Your new Phone Bill is $" + totalAmount);
ReadKey();
```

I am trying to calculate the correct Phone Bill Charge by adding rate and surge to phonebill as follows
phoneBill + rate + surge should equal/output 103.13 but for some reason the output I get is 75.35... How can I fix the output so it outputs 103.13?

Tried addition, multiplcation and division symbols within double totalAmount = phoneBill + rate + surge; also tried phonebill + (rate + surge) and (phonebill + rate) + surge with multiplication, addition, division symbols and still didn't compute 103.13.. how to fix this error?

Comment: How did you calculate that 75 + 0.25 + 0.1 should be 103.13??

Comment: You get `75.35` because that is how addition works. (`75 + 0.10 + 0.25 == 75.35`).  If you want a different answer, you need a different formula, perhaps involving some multiplication.

Comment: Monetary calculations should use decimal, not double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to add a 25% surcharge, then you should multiply by 125%, not 25%. Multiplying by 25% is actually a 75% discount (because you're only charging them 25% of the original amount).

Change `rate` to 1.1 (representing 110%) and `surge` to 1.25 (representing 125%) and multiply. The result is 103.125, so once you round to two decimal places you'll get the right answer.

Comment: Thanks, your post works... By no means am I a mathematician. Lol thanks!